# TextBox in mvc 3 shows zero value at application start

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

So in my model I have:

```
public int Number {get; set;}
```

in my View I call:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number, new { id = "Number" })
```

When I run application there is 0 value in TextBox.

I tried to change model like this:

```
public int? Number {get; set;}
```

but then i get exception...However I have in my model

```
public decimal? Price {get; set;}
```

and in my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { id = "Price" })
```

and when i run this textbox is empty and everything is ok. Does someone explain why int can't be a nullable type in this case? The exception I get is `Method not found: 'Int32'`

The goal is not to have 0 value in textbox but normal empty textbox

Comment: Could you post the exception that you're getting?

Comment: Method not found: 'Int32 WebUI.Model.SomeModel.get_Price()'.

Comment: @TheMentor - What is get_Price()?  Where is this called?  Is this called from your model?  Could you post the view and the model so that we can get a clear picture please.

Comment: So...the model and view are exactly like this. Try test project with one model and one view with one text box. In model you have int property.

Comment: Ok..now it works. As it seems the problem was that when i just change model property int to int? there was exception. I solved it that I delete textbox in view and just type everything again...lol...strange but now it works

Comment: @TheMentor Hey, thanks actually I get the same exception in the same scenario - I also removed that field from view and add it again and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Validation in your View like this :

> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { id = "Price" })
>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)

And in your controller you have to verifay if your model state is valide.

```
 If(ModelState.IsValide)
{
// code if all is ok
}
else
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error Message");
                  return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: I have jQuery validation. Validation is not the problem. The problem is that if you have int property in model the textbox shows defult 0 value. With decimal I solved this problem with nullable types. But when I try the same with int it throws an exception.